# Alternative to HttpNotFound in MVC2

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to learn ASP.Net MVC from the asp.net website sample application [MVCMovieApplication](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view). This application was written for MVC3. I am stuck at the below part. Can someone help me with this issue?

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
    if (movie == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(movie);
}
```

**Error:**

```
The Name 'HTTPNotFound' does not exist in the current context.
```

Comment: What do you want to do in case Move is null? render a message back to user that no records founds can use Model.Errors or ViewBag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [HttpNotFound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg453938%28v=vs.98%29) method and the related [HttpStatusCodeResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult%28v=vs.98%29) and it's inheritors like  `HttpNotFoundResult` are new features added in MVC3. That why it's not working in MVC2.

So either you upgrade to MVC3 (even MVC4 is released as RTM as of this week)

or you can create your own `ActionResult` to return the 404 status code:

```
public class HttpNotFoundResult : ActionResult
{
    private const int NotFoundCode = 404;

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = NotFoundCode;
    }
}
```

And you in your action method:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
    if (movie == null)
    {
        return new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }
    return View(movie);
}
```

Comment: thank you.. I am pretty new to Web developement..I think i need to look at what is happening behind these autogenerated code from tutorial